# Extracting white areas form an image with C# or Aforge.Net

Tags: c#, image, aforge, accord.net

Im facing with a problem that is drive me crazy, i hope that there is a better way to solve it!

My program get an image from webcam that contains 6 black numbers in 6 white squares!

Something like this:

[image]

The main problem is that the background is not black, but azure AND each webcams have an Auto BackLight correction different, fot this reason the bright level of each image is different too.

So my approach to Extract the white square blobs is to try to remove the azure/blue areas from the image, apply an grayscale filter, and finally start a cycle that do this:

1. set the thresold at 250 (max is 255)
2. apply the thresold `new Threshold( thres ).Apply(image);`
3. see if contains 6 or more squares blobs
4. if not, decrease threshold by 5 and go to step 2. (if thresold is less of 200, exit)
5. Six or more squares founded

This cycle is used to compensate the difference in the bright level of each image.

Is a very heavy computational approach and i dont know how i can improve or change this!
Is there a function in aForge or snippet C# code that can help me to improve the extraction of these areas? Anyone can suggest me a better way to do this?

Comment: Seeing the watermark, I laughed

Comment: The image is used only as example, to let understand better the question!

If you think that watermarked images are funny go to shutterstock.com
I think you will laught a lot there.